# Unit testing silverlight where does this live?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, location

Im tring to start unit testing with silverlight and some of the samples online use the following statements

```
EnqueueCallback
EnqueueConditional
EnqueueTestComplete
```

where do these live?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok found my answer. If your test inherits from WorkItemTest (or PresentationTest, or SilverlightTest), you’ll be able to call from your tests:

```
TestComplete()
```

Instructs the framework that your test method is finished, and to move onto the next result. This can be added to event callbacks, delegates, etc. You should not do any more work or your test after calling this.

```
EnqueueTestComplete
```

Enqueues an action to call TestComplete. This is the most-used way of calling TestComplete when a set of work is done, and would typically be the last Enqueue* method call.

```
EnqueueCallback
```

Enqueues an Action (delegate, simple lambda, etc.). The work item effectively calls the Action, then moves on. Alternatively, this enqueue method also takes an array of Actions, allowing you to chain many Action calls together in order.

```
EnqueueConditional
```

Takes a Func conditional statement / predicate. Each time the work item is evaluated, the function is called. When it returns True, the work item is complete and execution will continue. After each invoke of the predicate, the test framework will unwind the stack, allowing other work to happen, before coming back to try the condition again.

```
EnqueueDelay
```

This method will enqueue a work item that takes either a TimeSpan object or an integer representing the number of milliseconds at minimum to delay before continuing. This is not an exact timer, but rather, a way to ensure that at least a minimum amount of time continues. It is more like a DoEvents call than it is like a Sleep call, since it will not block the UI thread.